# How to overlay shapely.Polygon on tiff image

Tags: python, geospatial, shapely, rasterio

I have an oblique image of a building, saved in a TIFF. That image is georeferenced using GCPs (using ESPG:32617). Additionally, I have a `shapely.Polygon` that's coordinates of the same building in latitude and longitude (so EPSG:4326). Coordinates and the image are from different sources.
I want to display both the image and polygon using the same reference frame, so I can verify that they align.
Here are results of `gdalinfo` on the TIFF file (link to file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BhbAd-KNmta7HEAxAPj8gYYBtgmni6Ge/view?usp=sharing)):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: oblique_N.tiff
Size is 115, 317
GCP Projection = 
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 17N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-81,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Between 84°W and 78°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Bahamas. Ecuador - north of equator. Canada - Nunavut; Ontario; Quebec. Cayman Islands. Colombia. Costa Rica. Cuba. Jamaica. Nicaragua. Panama. United States (USA)."],
        BBOX[0,-84,84,-78]],
    ID["EPSG",32617]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (98.3105276672193,0.120036521323868) -> (581069.63551352,2851093.99523912,271)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (15.8348654576047,316.879963478676) -> (581056.130608335,2851042.88431689,271)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (115,304.815517974796) -> (581069.948644366,2851042.96910577,271)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (0,15.4405225192958) -> (581055.817530873,2851093.91044916,271)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  317.0)
Upper Right (  115.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  115.0,  317.0)
Center      (   57.5,  158.5)
Band 1 Block=112x320 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=112x320 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=112x320 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
```

Here's the polygon:

```
POLYGON ((-87.6388310614825 41.8948365045333, -87.6387464180662 41.8948376193115, -87.6386545 41.8948393, -87.6386589556933 41.8949865342181, -87.6388292759657 41.8949865342181, -87.6388310614825 41.8948365045333))
```

Here's my attempt to do that using rasterio:

```py
import rasterio
import rasterio.warp
import rasterio.plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely


def show_tiff_oblique(filename, polygon, ax):
    def show_tiff_oblique(filename, polygon, ax):
    src = rasterio.open(filename, 'r')
    tiff_crs = src.gcps[1]
    polygon_crs = rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg(4326)
    src_transform = rasterio.transform.from_gcps(src.gcps[0])
    projected_polygon = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(polygon_crs, tiff_crs, polygon.__geo_interface__)
    
    points = []
    for x, y in projected_polygon['coordinates'][0]:
        points.append(~src_transform * (x, y))
    reprojected_polygon = shapely.Polygon(points)
    
    rasterio.plot.show(src, transform=src_transform, ax=ax)
    ax.plot(*reprojected_polygon.exterior.xy, 'r')
```

<strike>Resulting plot is wrong, according to it building and image are in totally different places, the difference is millions in magnitude.</strike>
Resulting plot doesn't quite align with the building, sometimes quite wildy. I can't tell if it's due to the quality of data or if it's a matter of bad transformation somewhere along the way.
Sample `~src_transform`:

```
| 0.74,-0.02,-259398.65|
| 0.49,-0.52, 2201773.68|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
```

My intuition tells me that I'm not using transforms correctly, in particular I think I'm not retrieving rotation of the image properly (it's an oblique so in most cases it's rotated). However, I wasn't able to find an example of how to retrieve that.

EDIT: Added link to the [TIFF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BhbAd-KNmta7HEAxAPj8gYYBtgmni6Ge/view?usp=sharing).
EDIT2: Improved code based on my own findings.

Comment: Can you provide your `.tiff` file for reproducing your example ?

Comment: @HMH1013 I've added link to the TIFF file at your request

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer to the question, it's just an analysis of the data.**

First I verified the location of the `.tiff` in Qgis, as shown below. The area inside the red box is the .tiff image, and the lower layer is Google Satellite.The `.tiff` image is located in **Miami**.

Here we have a coordinate for example : `x : 581063.887, y :2851069.988`

[image]

Then I checked a coordinate in the `Plygon`, `lat : 41.8948365045333 lon : -87.6388310614825`, which corresponds this picture :
[image]

Which is located in **Chicago**.

The distance between the `.tiff` and the `Polygon` is nearly **1906Km**.

So the coordinates of the polygon should be wrong and you need to reselect your polygon.